# number of residues modulo $2^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am looking at Walter D. Stangl's paper "Counting Squares in $\mathbb{Z}_n$", and I have a question about the following part of a proof:

[image]

My question is why must $c \equiv 2^{n-1} \pm b \mod 2^n$? I see that $c \equiv 2^{n-1} - b \mod 2^n$comes from $(b+c) \equiv 2^{n-1} \mod 2^n$, but if $(b - c) \equiv 2^{n-1} \mod 2^n$, solving that yields $c \equiv b - 2^{n-1}\mod 2^n$. Where does the plus sign come from?

Comment: Ah silly me. It's because $-2^{n-1} \equiv 2^{n-1} \mod{2^n}$, since $2^n$ divides $-2^{n-1} - 2^{n-1} = -2^n$.